# Sculpture turning black. (most likely beginner problem)

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting, color, object-mode, sculpt-mode

I recently starting using blender and I have been encountering several problems. i usually find the solutions on the Internet, but this time I havent found anything that helped me.
After working for about 20 minutes of a face my mesh suddenly turned black. When I tried to change the mesh color it said it was white (eventhough it was black)  and nothing happend when I tried to change it it. How it looks in Edit/sculpture mode in shown in the pictures below. In objektive mode it looks the same as in sculpture mode.
Please help me change back the mesh to white.
[image] [image: edit mode]

Comment: I guess you have masked your whole object. Press ALT + M in sculptmode to clear the mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Viewport Shading is on Wireframe (upper right hand corner of the 3D View window, the four sphere graphic buttons, the first one is highlited).  Sculpting usually requires a dense mesh, so Wireframe, which shows all the edges of all the polygon faces, will make that black unless it's selected, then it'll be orange.

For sculpting you probably want your Viewport Shading on Solid (upper right hand corner of the 3D View window, the four sphere graphics, the second one is Solid).  Once you've done that click the carat down-arrow symbol to the right of the sphere graphic buttons, you'll get more options to show the surface of your model to best advantage while sculpting.

You also have X-Ray enabled (the button with the cube graphic to the left of the Viewport Shading buttons).  This shows the normally hidden areas of your mesh, which in Wireframe will make it look even denser.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It worked!